# finding the index of the maximum in a matrix in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, set

I have a matrix. I want to find the index of the maximum value in each row of the matrix.
the problem is that this matrix is the result of another algorithm so I can not use numpy ways to do.

```
[[  6.02   6.02   6.02   6.02
    6.02  6.02   6.02  9.94
    6.02  6.02]
 [  4.63  4.63  4.63  4.63
    4.63  4.63   4.63  4.63
    9.95  4.63]
 [  4.54   4.54   4.54  4.54
    4.54   9.95   4.54   4.54
    4.54   4.54]]
```

so the output for this woill be :
[7,8,5]

I wanted to loop over the each rows in matrix, then I had a row, but the problem was that it was like this:

```
   a =[  6.02   6.02   6.02   6.02
        6.02  6.02   6.02  9.94
        6.02  6.02]
```

As you see there is no format for that. I mean there is no comma between them, so I can not behave that like set or list again.

when I write `a.` there is no method,

**Update**

this is actually the output of this `lda_x=lda.fit_transform(corpus)`

Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Completely unclear what you are talking about. Is that a text-file, or a list of lists, or what? (The confusion comes from the fact, that there is no code included)

Comment: @sascha its a matrix like the one I have included, and I want the index of the maximum in each row.

Comment: There is no matrix in python. Be precise. What you posted can be a string, a string-representation of lists of lists, str-repr of a numpy matrix, some copy-paste from an text-editor... If it's a list of lists, just do the nested for loops. It's hard to tell what's your problem.

Comment: @sascha many thanks for your explanations. as I mentioned its an output of some process. I updated in some part, is it clear now? can we consider this as the way it is, and calculate the output like the thing I want without considering what it really is?

Comment: No! Programming is all about types! If you don't tell us what types are you using in which part of your program there is no help. (How do i sum up ```a``` and ```b```? -> ```a+b```. Yeah sure, this works for a=b=numbers; but the result a+b when both are strings is something completely different. Types matter!)

Comment: @sascha this is the output of Latent Dirichlet Allocation algorithm :(

Comment: Brilliant. LDA from matlab->text->readtext, from c-wrapper, from fortran-wrapper, from sklearn? from some other lib? from standard-input?... I want to make sure you understand the problem here. I doubt every semi-professional LDA-code will return numpy-arrays or scipy-sparse arrays. But well... Who knows what you are doing exactly.

Comment: I didnt know it may help :| sorry for that, sklearn actually

Comment: i will update some part please look at after 1 min

Comment: This lib returns an numpy array and you probably think printing out some row to the console represents the internal state (missing commas), it's not (what you see in the console has nothing to do with the internals; an index row is just an array of a specific dim)! Just use numpy's functions or the nested loop.

Comment: I put the code that created this matrix, does it helpful now?

Comment: @sascha do u have any idea whch way may help me? if I did know what it really is , I did not ask the question in this way :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A general remark:**

It's obvious you are missing a lot of programming basics and should read way more tutorials. Using sklearn without knowing, that it's completely based on numpy and scipy-arrays shows some lack of knowledge.

I don't think you should do complex ML-stuff like that without understanding those concepts.

#### Code (just to show the steps; that code makes not much sense!):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation


X = np.random.uniform(size=(10,20))

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(max_iter=5,
                                learning_method='online',
                                learning_offset=50.,
                                random_state=0)
X_new = lda.fit_transform(X)

print('transformed data')
print(X_new)

print('row-wise maximums')
print(np.amax(X_new, axis=1))
```

#### Output:

```
transformed data
[[ 0.00827835  0.00827806  0.00827819  0.92549556  0.00827816  0.00827812
   0.00827862  0.00827827  0.00827855  0.00827812]
 [ 0.00864627  0.00864591  0.00864594  0.92218549  0.00864589  0.00864588
   0.00864651  0.0086461   0.00864617  0.00864584]
 [ 0.00761386  0.00761349  0.00761361  0.93147708  0.0076135   0.00761359
   0.00761399  0.00761363  0.00761376  0.0076135 ]
 [ 0.00987778  0.0098773   0.00987748  0.91110236  0.00987731  0.00987739
   0.00987797  0.00987747  0.00987762  0.00987731]
 [ 0.00902489  0.00902451  0.00902467  0.9187762   0.00902463  0.00902457
   0.00902629  0.00902484  0.00902484  0.00902455]
 [ 0.0106997   0.01069926  0.01069952  0.90370346  0.01069944  0.0106994
   0.01070011  0.01069987  0.01069985  0.01069938]
 [ 0.00869799  0.00869761  0.00869767  0.92172003  0.00869759  0.0086976
   0.00869823  0.00869782  0.00869789  0.00869756]
 [ 0.00830867  0.0083084   0.00830849  0.92522278  0.00830843  0.00830836
   0.00830908  0.00830855  0.00830887  0.00830837]
 [ 0.00873503  0.00873454  0.00873457  0.92138779  0.00873453  0.00873451
   0.00873501  0.00873467  0.00873481  0.00873453]
 [ 0.01097472  0.01097405  0.01097429  0.90123112  0.01097416  0.01097427
   0.01097458  0.01097437  0.01097436  0.01097409]]
row-wise maximums
[ 0.92549556  0.92218549  0.93147708  0.91110236  0.9187762   0.90370346
  0.92172003  0.92522278  0.92138779  0.90123112]
```

If you want the indices instead of the values:

```
print(np.argmax(X_new, axis=1))
```

which outputs:

```
row-wise maximums
[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
```

Comment: I believe you are right, I defenitely change the way I am doing and take your advice a good thing for following my goals, thanks my friend. do opologize for this kind of question it wasnt professional behaviour

Comment: We all start somewhere. But make sure you praise the good documentation of python, numpy, scipy and sklearn. All are top-notch!

Comment: you are right I should put a good time on the basic then go throgh ML, actually just under pressure to prepare some thing for monday, many thanks again. can you please update the answer as argmax as I was searching for the index then I will upvote that as the answer?

Comment: I think the current state of that answer is ok. argmax is already mentioned and i think it's okay to show both.